# Array cascades its changed to secondary temp array in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I came across a unique (to me), and quite puzzling situation.

I have an array of three values.

focal[x,y,z]

these values change based on user input.

however when the change occurs, they are logged into a new array to test for valid changed

A simplified psuedo version of my code:

```
var temp:Array = focal; //I have even changed this to a const at times but to no avail

//changes to array are made like thus:
focal[1]++;
focal[0]--;

if(valid){
doStuff();
} else {
focal = temp;
}
```

However, when the focal[1]++; focal[0]--; ect, ect, code takes place. It also changed the temp array.

and since it changes my temp, it never resets me original code back to its previous nature.

I have never seen this behavior and its kinda throwin' me off. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are doing like this:

```
var temp:Array = focal; // Both array variables refer to the same array.
```

if you want to make a backup or temporary array you need to copy all the componetns from one to another:

```
var baseArray : Array = [0, 0, 0];
var tempArray : Array = baseArray.slice();

baseArray[0]++;
baseArray[1] += 2;
baseArray[2] += 3;

trace ( baseArray ); // output: 1,2,3
trace ( tempArray ); // output: 0,0,0
```

Comment: I see, so basically I was making another pointer. Strange. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I add the deep copy method to the (very good) post by Jevgenij:

```
import flash.utils.ByteArray; 

function clone(source:Object):* 
{ 
    var myBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    myBA.writeObject(source); 
    myBA.position = 0; 
    return(myBA.readObject()); 
}
```

[More informations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee7.html) here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee7.html